# Invalid UpdateExpression when using parameter from ValueMap as index (REMOVE myArray[:index])

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I try to remove an element from an array. This operation

```
UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
            .withPrimaryKey("id", id)
            .withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#P", "myArray"))
            .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withInt(":index", index))
            .withUpdateExpression("REMOVE #P[:index]");

    table.updateItem(updateItemSpec);
```

results with `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: ":index", near: "[:index]"`

If I remove ValueMap and concat string like this `"REMOVE #P["+index+"]"` it works fine but this solution looks ugly (like old bad SQL injection stuff). Is there a way to provide an index as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

> REMOVE - Removes one or more attributes from an item

REMOVE - The **`UpdateExpression`** is expected to have attribute name only for REMOVE. It should not contain attribute value similar to **`SET`**.

There is no alternative other than **String concatenation** by some means.